# add click to hover event

Tags: jquery, css

i need to customize a mega menu that opens only on hover (display:none/display:block).

i need it to work also on click so  i added this

```
     $(".menuitem_fullwidth").click(function(){
        $(this).find(".dropdown_fullwidth").css( "display", "block" );

           return false;
        });
```

but now it opens on click but  when i click on a different menu item nothing happens

only the first menu(first click) always stay open and doesnt close or change to another item

Comment: Can you provide your html and css as well or make a http://jsfiddle.net? I'm sure `$(this).find('.dropdown_fullwidth').toggleClass('active');` should work well but I can't tell for sure.

Comment: From what I see, you might open it, but you never close it, which might be a good hint as of why the first menu clicked stays open ;)

Comment: user existing hover code , and add click event to that

Comment: Could you paste the html generated by the mega menu? Maybe you are selecting only the first item but you should do that more generic. Regards.

Comment: why  $( ".menuitem_fullwidth").unbind( "click" ); doesnt work here?

Comment: the css and jquery are 10 km long the code comes from  a built in plugin that  i was trying to gently override:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to close all the menus first, then open the one that's clicked

```
 $(".menuitem_fullwidth").click(function(){
        $(".dropdown_fullwidth").css( "display", "none" );
        $(this).find(".dropdown_fullwidth").css( "display", "block" );

           return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
 $(".menuitem_fullwidth").click(function(){
    $(".dropdown_fullwidth").css({display: "none"});
    $(this).find(".dropdown_fullwidth").css( "display", "block" );
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

take the hover code that you already had and just add the click event to it.  You can have multiple events bound to the same code

```
$('#element').on('hover click', function() {
  // code here..
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i assume you are trying to open one menu at a time, you can use toggle,

```
$(document).on('click','.menuitem_fullwidth'(function(){
        $('.dropdown_fullwidth').toggle();
        $(this).find(".dropdown_fullwidth").toggle();
           return false;
        });
```

Comment: thank you but i think the toggle event was deprecated in jQuery 1.8